# Tomcat 7 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main - Mac OS X 10.6

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

I have unpacked the tar file in /usr/local and created a symbolic link in /Library/Tomcat.  From there I made all .sh files in /bin executable.  Upon startup, I get nothing, including a normal "could not connect" upon visiting localhost:8080.  Checking my catalina.out shows "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main" for each instance that I tried to start it up.  I have followed numerous tutorials, including those [here](http://www.malisphoto.com/tips/tomcatonosx.html) and [here](http://wolfpaulus.com/journal/mac/tomcat7), but nothing seems to help the problem.

EDIT:  Here is the trace when starting Tomcat

> Using CATALINA_BASE:   /Library/Tomcat
>   Using CATALINA_HOME:   /Library/Tomcat
>   Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /Library/Tomcat/temp
>   Using JRE_HOME:        /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK/Home
>   Using CLASSPATH:       /Library/Tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/Library/Tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar

Comment: have you set `CATALINA_HOME` environment variable?

Comment: Show us the stack traces from the logfile.

Comment: we still need to see which method is not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have incomaptible jar files in your classpath you use to launch Tomcat, (For example Tomcat 7 may depend on a library foo.jar version 1.2 but you have 1.1 installed)

The only way to know for sure is to see the strack trace (what method is Tomcat expecting and in which class). That will lead you to your problem.

Comment: Can you give me some tips as to how I should obtain said stack trace?

Comment: what are the lines below `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main`? That would be your stack trace, also how did you launch tomcat? could you show us the command you used?

Comment: Every line in catalina.out is "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main".  There is only one of those exceptions per startup, so it doesn't make it very far in the process.  To start tomcat, I cd to /bin and simply run ./startup.sh.

Comment: I found out that this is the section of the catalina.sh where the problem is occuring:`eval \"$_RUNJAVA\" \"$LOGGING_CONFIG\" $JAVA_OPTS $CATALINA_OPTS \
      -Djava.endorsed.dirs=\"$JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS\" -classpath \"$CLASSPATH\" \
      -Djava.security.manager \
      -Djava.security.policy==\"$CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.policy\" \
      -Dcatalina.base=\"$CATALINA_BASE\" \
      -Dcatalina.home=\"$CATALINA_HOME\" \
      -Djava.io.tmpdir=\"$CATALINA_TMPDIR\" \
      org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap "$@" start`

Comment: bootstrap.jar is definitely on the classpath.  I'm really puzzled as to why it cannot find Bootstrap.main().

Comment: can we see the full $CLASSPATH from your previous reply

Comment: `CLASSPATH = /Library/Tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/Library/Tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar`.  I tried running `java -jar /Library/Tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar` directly and received the same error.  I have tried downloading other versions and replacing the bootstrap.jar, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: If you tried running the jar fil directly and it didn't work, then I'm not sure what is going on, sorry